# Custom square views margins padding issue

Tags: java, android, view, margins

I'm trying to make a table NxM (in my case 2x5) with square views.

All is ok but **with not-zero margin and/or padding** not all views are of the same dimensions, showing some background between rows for some cells.

Here the xml and the java code.

I tried even without TableLayout just one row with one LinearLayout, with FrameLayout, but it's the same. Trying with different emulators I get different number of cells with same dimensions.

So the problem is putting in same line many views with same squared dimensions (with a background. Tried without bg image, just with colored bg, same issue).

Thanks a lot!

Layout:

```
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"   >

        <com.myName.myProject.NodeContainer
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/tile_sq" 
      >
        </com.myName.myProject.NodeContainer>

        <com.myName.myProject.NodeContainer
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/tile_sq" >
        </com.myName.myProject.NodeContainer>

        <com.myName.myProject.NodeContainer
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/tile_sq" >
        </com.myName.myProject.NodeContainer>

        <com.myName.myProject.NodeContainer
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/tile_sq" >
        </com.myName.myProject.NodeContainer>

        <com.myName.myProject.NodeContainer
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/tile_sq" >
        </com.myName.myProject.NodeContainer>
    </TableRow>
 <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <com.myName.myProject.NodeContainer
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/tile_sq" >
        </com.myName.myProject.NodeContainer>

        <com.myName.myProject.NodeContainer
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/tile_sq" >
        </com.myName.myProject.NodeContainer>

        <com.myName.myProject.NodeContainer
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/tile_sq" >
        </com.myName.myProject.NodeContainer>

        <com.myName.myProject.NodeContainer
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/tile_sq" >
        </com.myName.myProject.NodeContainer>

        <com.myName.myProject.NodeContainer
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/tile_sq" >
        </com.myName.myProject.NodeContainer>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Class:

```
package com.myName.myProject;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class NodeContainer extends LinearLayout {

    public NodeContainer(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public NodeContainer(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        final int width = getMeasuredWidth();
        setMeasuredDimension(width, width);

    }
}
```

Comment: Show the screen where the problem could be seen. It's quite hard to where is the problem.

Comment: Here is the image. Thanks [link](http://s27.postimg.org/595nb4n5f/Capture.png)